# Oracle: Renaming column headers from stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

This should be trivial but for some reason I'm scratching my head over it.

I'd simply like to assign a column name to a rowset returned from a sproc. Unfortunately the syntax that works in SQLPlus generates a compiler error when used within a sproc created in Oracle SQL Developer.

**From MSSQL:**   SELECT 'foobar' as 'Column Header'

**From SQLPlus:** SELECT 'foobar          ' as "Column Header" from dual;

**Oracle SQL Developer Sproc:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sproc01 AS
BEGIN
   SELECT 'foobar          ' as "Column Header" from dual;
END sproc01;

Error(3,3): PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement
```

This also fails with the same error -

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROCEDURE1 AS 
MyValue NVARCHAR2(40) := 'foobar    ';
BEGIN
  select MyValue as "My Value" from dual;
END PROCEDURE1;
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're coming from a SQL Server background, one of the important things to realize is that stored procedures (prior to 12c) cannot return implicit result sets.  You can define a stored procedure that has a `sys_refcursor` as an `OUT` parameter or a function that returns a `sys_refcursor`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my_proc( p_rc OUT SYS_REFCURSOR )
AS
BEGIN
  OPEN p_rc 
   FOR SELECT 'foobar' as "Column Header"
         FROM dual;
END;
```

or

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_func
  RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
IS
  l_rc sys_refcursor;
BEGIN
  OPEN l_rc
   FOR SELECT 'foobar' as "Column Header"
         FROM dual;
  RETURN l_rc;
END;
```

It would be more common, though, to embed this logic in a view rather than a PL/SQL block

```
CREATE VIEW my_view
AS
SELECT 'foobar' as "Column Header"
  FROM dual;
```

Answer (score 2):

In PL/SQL procedure you must assign result somewhere. It could be variable, for example. That's why it complains about missing `INTO` clause. It has nothing to do with the column name.